# django admin populate a field while saving model

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    net_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sold_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    profit = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
```

Here in admin when I give`net_price` and `sold_price` and save it I want the profit to be calculated automatically. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [`.clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method in your models to calculate the value of `profit` if not supplied.

Doing this will set the `profit` attribute on the instance if the value was not provided from the  admin.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    net_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sold_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    profit = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)

    def clean(self):
        if getattr(self, 'profit', None) is None: # check that current instance has 'profit' attribute not set
            self.profit = self.sold_price - self.net_price # calculate and assign 'profit'
```

Comment: clean method in model ?

Comment: Yes, we can create a `clean()` method in the model to handle this.